# How to check that an equation can represent a one dimensional traveling wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I want to check if the following equation can represent a one dimensional traveling wave.

$$f(z,t)=e^{-az^2-bt^2}$$

I know the general form of a traveling one dimensional wave is

$$y=f(x+vt)$$

However, I'm having a hard time getting there. So far, I've tried taking the second partial derivatives with respect to x and t of the given function to see if it satisfies the one-dimensional wave equation

$$d^2y/dx^2=1/v^2*d^2y/dt^2$$

But since I have a and b in the equation, I'm not sure how to get there.
*My question is: what approach should I use to check if an equation can represent a one dimensional traveling wave?*

Comment: z^2 - t^2 = ...?